# OpenVR. Rendering in OpenGL without SDL

Tags: opengl, sdl, virtual-reality, openvr

Is this possible in nature? What role of SDL library in OpenVR API? Does it needed for OpenGL context or only for mirroring the stereo image to SDL window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. If you don't use SDL, you'll have to create your rendering context and window by yourself. The whole code would be too long for this answer, but on Windows you could use functions like `CreateWindowEx` and `wglCreateContext`. OpenVR doesn't require anything different from a normal context setup, but you need to use a somewhat modern version of OpenGL (4.1 at least works for me).

Comment: So, will this window be shown on monitor (native machine monitor, not HMD) just like SDL window? Can I hide it?

Comment: @drewpts It is shown on monitor. I haven't tried hiding it so I don't know.

Comment: All hardware that supports OpenVR (and Oculus) also supports OpenGL 4.5, so there's rarely a reason not to just request a 4.5 context if you're building for VR.